# Data fields switched in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When I create a new row in my database with sequelize, two of the data points end up in the wrong columns, like they are being switched.

Here's what I'm creating:

```
Product.create({
        title: 'title',
        price: 'price',
        description: 'description',
        imageUrl: 'imageUrl'
    }).then( result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
```

And here is what actually ends up in the database:

```
{
   title: 'title',
   price: price,
   description: 'imageUrl', // switched with imageUrl
   imageUrl: 'description'        // switched with description 
}
```

The most confusing thing is that the data logged to the console is correct:

```
{
    id: 15,
    title: 'title',
    price: 'price',
    description: 'description',
    imageUrl: 'url',
    updatedAt: 2020-12-27T16:31:29.541Z,
    createdAt: 2020-12-27T16:31:29.541Z
  }
```

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT- As requested here is a model definition:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})
```

Also as requested, here is the result of SQL logging the commands sequelize is running:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `price`, `description`, `imageUrl`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `products` AS `product`;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `products` (`id`,`title`,`price`,`description`,`imageUrl`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Comment: Show a model definition

Comment: Turn on SQL logging in Sequelize and show a generated SQL

Comment: Can you look at what Sequelize passed to `INSERT`?